# How to increase the counter on my Foreign Key Model

Tags: django

I have the following doubt:
Let's assume that my Django project has the following models:

```
class State(models.Model):
    initials = models.CharField('Initials', max_length=2, blank = False)
    name     = models.CharField('State', max_length=50, blank = False)
    count    = models.IntegerField('Foo Counter', default=0)
    ....


class Foo(models.Model):
   name  = models.CharField('Name', max_length=50, blank = False)
   state = models.ForeignKey(State, verbose_name='State', related_name='state_fk', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING),
   ....
```

So i have a form to add Foo instances to my db:

```
class FooForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model  = Foo
       fields = '__all__'
```

this is the view.py file:

```
def home(request):
    template_name = 'home.html'
    form = FooForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        salvar = form.save(commit=False)
        salvar.save()
        return redirect('FooApp:home')
    else:
        context = {
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request, template_name, context)
```

I need that, every time the user registers a new 'Foo' the counter of the 'State' chosen by him is increased by 1, i search a lot here and in docs of Django but i could not find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need `count` defined as a model field if it's dependent on a database computation, and not something that will be entered from outside?

As mentioned before, you can add logic in the application to update `count` value from `State` to `self.foo_set.count()`

However, I think that it might worth looking into a different approach which would be defining a `cached_property` on `State` as it follows:

```
@cached_property
def count(self):
    return self.foo_set.count()
```

In this way, you'll be able to access `State.count` wherever you want in the application and get the right value without worrying to keep it updated.

Comment: Oh thats nice, Ty

Answer (score 0):

You may not need to keep track of count manually like that.  For any instance of State you can always call:

```
state.foo_set.count()
```

That will always give you the current count.

Comment: I guess I was not clear enough. Each registered Foo corresponds to a single 'State', each time the register occurs I want the corresponding state.count to be incremented. (English isnt my native language, ;/ )

Comment: I separate State in a new Model just for mantain my db normalized by 3NF (here I post an simplified case, my real case has more variables that are not worth repeat on db)

Comment: I still think my suggestion could do what you want.  Where you would use `state.count` use `state.foo_set.count()` instead.